# Select Distinct records from 3 different columns

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, subquery, codeigniter-3

I have a scenario like this.

[image]

There are 3 different columns. UserId, Coin and Wallet. I want to select only distinct Coins and Wallets if there are any for a specific User. How can I achieve this. In the image below, you can see what I currently have and what I want. I tried using sub-query for this but for some reason, it doesn't seem to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using union

```
select userid, coin as asset from tablename where coin is not null
union 
select userid, wallet from tablename where wallet is not null
```

Comment: Is there any way we can exclude the empty records?

Comment: It is still giving me an empty record for each user

Comment: try to use `WHERE wallet <> ''` and `WHERE coin <> ''`